# Issue with formula environment

Tags: r

The code below includes a simplified example that displays my issue. Not as simple as it could be but I didn't want to remove too much of the context.

When I create a formula using as.formula() and try to use that formula to fit a model to multiply imputed data, I get "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'outcome' not found". When I explicitly list the formula in the modeling statement (last line), no problem. Also, if I reference the formula in an analysis of a single dataset (i.e., no need for 'with'), also no problem. It seems clear that the problem is that the formula is created in the global environment, while I need it to look in the data frame for the variables named. I just don't understand R environments well enough to figure out how to work around this.

I am applying this code in simulations with a more complex set of models under several scenarios so my final line of code below is not really an option if I am to program these simulations at all efficiently.

Thanks for any advice!

```
library(MASS)
library(mitools)
library(lme4)

#Generate 3 small datasets to emulate multiply imputed data
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0.5, -0.7, -0.4, -0.4,
                  0.5, 1, -0.4, -0.2, -0.2, 
                  -0.7, -0.4, 1, 0.5, 0.4, 
                  -0.4, -0.2, 0.5, 1, 0.6,
                  -0.4, -0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1),5,5)

complete <- as.list(1:3)
for (i in 1:3){
  complete[[i]] <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n = 10, mu=c(0,0,0,0,0), Sigma=Sigma))
}


#Convert to longitudinal analysis format and imputationList object type
all.long <- imputationList(lapply(complete, reshape, varying=c("V3", "V4", "V5"), direction="long", 
                                   v.names="outcome", times=c(0,2,4)))

current.formula <-formula(outcome ~ 1 + time + (1 | id) + (0 + time | id) + V1 + V2)

#This does not work:
imp.fit <- with(data=all.long, lmer(current.formula, REML=TRUE))
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'outcome' not found


# This does work:
imp.fit <- with(all.long, lmer(outcome ~ 1 + time + (1 | id) + (0 + time | id) + V1 + V2, REML=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use lapply on the list of imputed data.frames:

```
current.formula <- formula(outcome ~ 1 + time + (1 | id) + (0 + time | id) + V1 + V2)
imp.fit2 <- lapply(all.long$imputations, function(dat) lmer(current.formula, REML=TRUE, data=dat))
```

This will give you the exact same results as when you call the formula directly.

Comment: Thanks, @htfy. I need a sign over my desk to remind me to think of lapply in more situations. I would, however, love to preseve a multiple imputation object type if possible to facilitate use of functions like MIcombine to pool results without extra steps to coerce the results into the proper structure.

Comment: @JBeau: Which object do want to have a multiple imputation type? As far as I can tell, the elements of `imp.fit` and `imp.fit2` have the same type. And you can use the `mitools` function on either: e.g. `MIextract(imp.fit2, fun=fixef)` should work. See [this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.lme4.devel/5522) for an example.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Thanks!  P.S. I realized too late that I should have accepted your edit prior to make an additional edit to my question so that you got the reputation points. Sorry!